# Order of multiple listeners to a same location in Firebase

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an activity with the Tab Layout. When the activity starts, I grab the object of my location and set activity title, find contacts photo uri from local contact's data and initialize fragments by passing that object to the fragments.

Stucture of object is like this:

```
eventId : {
    name: "Event Name",
    contacts: {
        -id1: {
             name: "Foo",
             email: foo@example.com
        },
        -id2: {
             name: "Bar",
             email: bar@example.com
        }
    },
    // Other stuff
}
```

Now, the object contains a list of contacts and contacts have email addresses. I load the contact's photos URI from the local contacts data on the phone by searching email address and add it to that object before sending it to fragments for initializing. So that, those fragments have the details of photo uris of contacts whenever they need to display the photo of the contact on screen.

Now, one tab is a fragment which shows the activity stream of that event and showed with FirebaseUI RecyclerView. And which has the references of contact ids from eventId. So on screen whenever I have a friend reference I grab the detail from the event Object.

It looks like this:

> Activity created -> Receives Event Data from Firebase -> Fetches the Photo Uris from local contact book -> Updates the Object -> Initialize the tab fragments with the Object (which contains contact details with photo uri)

But if the friends list is updated and new activity stream references to the contact that currently not hold by the object, it will crash.

So, what I am trying to achieve is, Whenever new data is updated, Activity fetches the new Event object, get the friends list, finds the contact photos uris and send updated object to the Fragments so that they can now reference the new contact.

One way I can do this is setting listener in the fragments as well as in activity. On updating contact list, activity can update its object again. When, the data changes fragments asks to the activity to provide the new data. But, if the listener in the fragment fires first in the fragment than activity, then activity might send the same data and app can crash.

The thing I can not dynamically fetches the uri in fragments is, there are lots of contacts and fetching it every single time affects scrolling performance.

Is there any order how the listeners will fire? In which order?

Or is there any better and simpler approach to this?

Thanks.

Comment: so you have a fragment which uses FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and listens to "event" node (the parent of "eventId" from your example)? and the fragment is attached to an activity which gets some data from the phone and then set the value to the firebase database where? and the new value is a "photo" child under a contact?

Comment: Hi @Wilik, Activity gets the data from the phone (contact's photo uri from email) and sends to the fragment. Fragment has firebase recycler adapter which references different node (not eventId) which contains contact's ids. Based on that contact Id, I show photo get from the data I received from the activity. Hope it clears the confusion